# Power Query - Add custom column based on values found in another lookup Query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I like to add a column in MainQuery and fill it up with values found in another LookupQuery based what it being able to find the matching unique value embedded in the text of column1 in my Main Query. if not found just return blank, null.  Thank you

Main Query

| Column1 |
| --- |
| ...111. |
| ..ABC.. |
| ..34C.. |
| ...xyz. |
| yyy..... |

Lookup Query

| Uniques |
| --- |
| 34C |
| ABC |
| 111 |

Desired Output in Main Query

| Column1 | New Column |
| --- | --- |
| ...111.. | 111 |
| ..ABC... | ABC |
| ..34C... | 34C |
| ....xyz. |  |
| yyy..... |  |

Answer (score 1):

Here's another method using `List.Accumulate` to loop through the lookup list.  Not sure which of the methods will be more efficient.

*Note: If there might be more than one lookup result for a given item in column 1, a small change in the List.Accumulate function can accommodate showing them all with a separator*

```
let

//Read in Main Query
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Main"]}[Content],
    Main = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),

//Read in Lookup Query as a list of text items
    Lookup = List.Buffer(
                List.Transform(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Lookup"]}[Content][Uniques], 
                    each Text.From(_))),
     
//add Column
    #"Add Column" = 
        Table.AddColumn(
            Main, "New Column", each 
                List.Accumulate(Lookup, 
                                null, 
                                (state, current)=> 
                                    if Text.Contains([Column1], current) 
                                        then current else state), 
                                        type nullable text)
in
    #"Add Column"
```

[image]

***Results***
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's a not a built-in join that does this, but you can cross-join followed by a filter.  And to Cross Join in PQ you add a custom column to one table containing the full value of the other table, then run Table.ExpandTableColumn.

EG

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WSjE0NFSK1YlWKk5Jc3RyNrY0BvMSs4uzgDLZxYlZKWnZxibOSrGxAA==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Column1 = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each Lookup),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom", {"Uniques"}, {"Uniques"}),
    #"Selected Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Expanded Custom", each Text.Contains([Column1], [Uniques]))
in
    #"Selected Rows"
```

Comment: Is this a method you would suggest over e.g. this nice approach using a conditional join? https://p3adaptive.com/2019/02/powerquerymagic-conditional-joins-using-table-selectrows/ How expensive is it to do this type of crossjoin where the full table is assigned to each row?

Comment: For me, at least, cross-join+filter is conceptually simpler.  But the approach you reference essentially performs a nested loop filter instead of generating the full cross-join may perf better with larger data.

Comment: LookupQuery could be loaded from your Excel data.